# Can I execute a COUNT() before GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, count, mysql-workbench

I am working on an mySQL assignment for school and I am stuck on a question. I am still new to mySQL. COUNT(o.customer_id) is not working the way I want. I want it to count the number of orders but it is counting all items. i.e. Customer 1 has 2 orders but it is returning 3 because one order has two items. I have three tables one with customers, another with orders than another with each item on each order. Ive posed my query below. Any help would be great.

```
SELECT email_address, COUNT(o.order_id) AS num_of_orders,
       SUM(((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity)) AS total
FROM customers c JOIN orders o
      ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
     JOIN order_items ot
      ON o.order_id = ot.order_id
GROUP BY o.customer_id
HAVING num_of_orders > 1
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As simple as use `Distinct` reserved word:

```
SELECT email_address, COUNT(distinct o.order_id) AS num_of_orders
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to count the DISTINCT number of orders.  Add a DISTINCT into the COUNT.  Although MySQL allows you to use the SELECT expression in the HAVING clause, it's not good practice to do so.

```
SELECT email_address, COUNT(DISTINCT o.order_id) AS num_of_orders,
       SUM(((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity)) AS total
FROM customers c JOIN orders o
      ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
     JOIN order_items ot
      ON o.order_id = ot.order_id
GROUP BY o.customer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.order_id) > 1
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: Changing the one line yielding the same results for me.

Comment: bups! Not for mysql ... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html (see second select sample)

Answer (score -1):

Just take out the join to items.  All it is doing is duplicating rows when there are multiple items.

```
SELECT email_address, COUNT(o.order_id) AS num_of_orders,
       SUM(((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity)) AS total
FROM customers c JOIN orders o
      ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY o.customer_id
HAVING COUNT(o.order_id) > 1
ORDER BY total DESC;
```